# How can I reduce the size of a Virtual Box VM?

Tags: virtualbox, compression

I have an Ubuntu Server installed in Virtualbox. Its `VDI file's size is 4.2G` and it has a Dynamically allocated drive. When I export it, the file size of the `OVA file is 1.4G`. I want to reduce the size of the OVA file somehow. I uninstalled all the unwanted programs and deleted unwanted files and then compacted the disk already. I also tried to compress the OVA file with 7zip, but that only decreases the size by 100MB.

The reason for doing so is because I want to share the VM with a friend of mine. What I usually do is once I am done working with the VM, I export it (File->Export Appliance) and then send the exported OVA file. Since working with a big size is not that convenient, I want to make it as small as possible. My final goal is to **make the OVA file smaller than 800MB** after I export it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am unclear what you have done to compact the disk.  Did you create a large file on the disk with 0's and then delete that?   If not, doing that will help significantly.

It occurs to me that you likely also have swap.  I expect that zeroing out the contents of the swap partition will make a substantial difference.   I have not tested this, but I expect you can do this as follows.

As root:

1. Identify your swap partition (usually this is listed in /etc/fstab).
2. Unmount swap, with "swapoff -a"
3. Write zero's to it - for example, if pv is installed "pv < /dev/zero > /dev/swap-drive or if you need to use dd "dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/swap-drive bs=40960"
4. Reformat swap drive "mkswap /dev/swap-drive"

If /boot is a separate partition you may need to "compact it" as well.   Likewise if you are using LVM and have resized volumes in the past you may want to create a volume with all the free space, zero it out and then delete it.

Comment: If this is not adequate, can you provide us more details of your filesystem.  For example, an output of ls -l /boot;  du -csh /var/*; lvs -a; blkid;

Comment: Actually, I didn't try this method, I used the VirtualboxManager.exe utility with the --compact flag. Can I get an approximate value of the size with which I can make this smaller? For example how much in MB I can compact?

Comment: No one can give you an estimate - it depends on how much the VM has been used.  The thing is that when a file is deleted, the index simply removes the file - the underlying data is still on the disk (and less compressible then a bunch of 0's).   By writing 0's to a file and then deleting it, you are converting that data to 0's, which compress very well.    Its really a matter of trying it and seeing.    (I **think** the --compact flag is simply working hard to create a better sparse filesystem, but its not going to 0 out the unused data as it doesnt know the filesystem on the VM)

Comment: As you have "I uninstalled all the unwanted programs and deleted unwanted files" I would expect the difference to be meaningful.